# Solve recurrence using SymPy

Tags: python, sympy

I am trying to solve this recurrence with SymPy but it's giving me `None`

Any ideas?

```
import sympy as sp

a = 1/6

y = sp.Function('y')
n = sp.symbols('n',integer=True)
f = y(n)- (a) * ( y(n-1) + y(n-2) + y(n-3) + y(n-4) + y(n-5) + y(n-6) )

y1 = a
y2 = y1 * a + a
y3 = y2 * a + y1 * a + a
y4 = y3 * a + y2 * a + y1 * a + a
y5 = y4 * a + y3 * a + y2 * a + y1 * a + a
y6 = y5 * a + y4 * a + y3 * a + y2 * a + y1 * a + a

s = sp.rsolve(f, y(n), {
    y(1) : y1, 
    y(2) : y2,
    y(3) : y3,
    y(4) : y4,
    y(5) : y5,
    y(6) : y6
}
)

print(s)
```

Comment: The general formula seems to be `y(n) = a*(a+1)**n`, but that doesn't fit into the given recursive pattern. By the way, to represent a fraction in sympy you need to avoid pure Python's division, e.g. `a = sp.S(1) / 6`.  See [sympy's gotchas](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/gotchas.html#python-numbers-vs-sympy-numbers).

Answer (score 1):

[edited response]

Try rewriting your recurrence so it refers to a limited number of previous terms, not *all previous* terms:

```
>>> from sympy import Rational
>>> a = Rational(1, 6)
>>> rsolve(y(n) - (1 + a)*y(n-1), y(n), [a])
(7/6)**n/6
>>> [_.subs(n,i) for i in range(6)] == [y1,y2,y3,y4,y5,y6]
True
```

Comment: What do you mean? My recurrence has different starting values i.e. different values for the first 6 terms in the sequence.

Comment: You have not given the recursive relationship in a way that can be used to generate the next term "as expected". You would have to write `y(n) - a*Sum(y(i), (i, 1, n-1))` to be general about it. But this form is not recognized; it can be written more simply as `y(n) - (1 + a)*y(n - 1)` and that form will give you an answer as shown in my answer.